# Django code to check the state of prometheus target such that it checks the state when the metrics data is scraped for that target

Tags: django, multithreading, prometheus, monitoring

The customer will click on process request button and the monitoringConfigurationMultipleVM API gets called, then for every successful exporter configuration, one new job for that vm and exporter combo gets added in prometheus.yml file, and then that job we are passing as a paramater to the checkprometheusTargetStatus fucntion to check the state of the target of that job that has been recently added to prometheus.yml file(in our case every job will have only one target). We are trying to check the prometheus target state after the target is being added in the prometheus.yml file which has a scrape interval of 5s, but if we try to check the state of the target right after the target is being added to the prometheus.yml file, then we get the "target does not exist or has no data" case. And if we introduce a delay i.e. by adding time.sleep(some sec time), then if the time duration of sleeping is less than the combined scrape interval time of all jobs recently added to prometheus, then it gives "target does not exist or has no data" as a result for first target and for rest of the targets it gives correct state i.e. either "up" or "down". What is the solution to get the state of all the targets correctly even regardless of how many targets we are passing to the checkprometheusTargetStatus  function?

## API in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def monitoringConfigurationMultipleVM(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            # Generation of unique request id for process request
            request_id = generate_unique_id()
            request_status = RequestStatus(
                reqID=request_id,
                user="APM",
                jobStatus="PROCESSING",
                jobStartTime=datetime.today().astimezone(pytz.utc)
            )
            while True:
                try:
                    request_status.save()
                    request_id = request_status.reqID
                    break
                except Exception:
                    request_status.reqID = generate_unique_id()
                    continue
            to_be_updated_request = RequestStatus.objects.get(reqID=request_id)

            try:
                configurationData = json.loads(request.body)
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid JSON data'}, status=400)
            for data in configurationData:
                ip_validation_flag = True
                try:
                    ipaddress.ip_address(data.get("vm"))
                except Exception:
                    ip_validation_flag = False
                status_tracking = StatusTracking(
                    reqID=request_status,
                    trackingID=generate_unique_id(),
                    vm=data.get("vm"),
                    connector=data.get("connector"),
                    connectorStatus="In Progress",
                    connectorStatusReason="Configuration in progress",
                    jobStartTime=datetime.today().astimezone(pytz.utc)
                )
                if ip_validation_flag == False:
                    status_tracking.exporterErrorLog = "Invalid IP address"
                status_tracking.save()
            task_id = ProcessRequest.delay(
                request_id).id
            result = AsyncResult(task_id)
            monitoringData = result.get()

            conf_data_list = []
            for i, data in enumerate(monitoringData, start=0):
                conf_data_dict = {}
                task_id = scriptExecution.delay(
                    data[2], configurationData[i]["username"], configurationData[i]["password"]).id
                print("Password:>>>>>>>>>>>", configurationData[i]["password"])
                result = AsyncResult(task_id)

                connectorStatusReason = result.get()

                to_be_updated = StatusTracking.objects.filter(
                    vm=data[2], connector=data[3], trackingID=data[9]).last()
                to_be_updated.jobID = task_id
                to_be_updated.jobStartTime = result.date_done

                to_be_updated.jobStatus = result.status
                to_be_updated.connectorStatusReason = connectorStatusReason

                flag = True

                if "ERROR-MSG: " in connectorStatusReason:
                    to_be_updated.connectorStatusReason = "FAILED TO CONFIGURE"
                    if to_be_updated.exporterErrorLog == None or to_be_updated.exporterErrorLog != "Invalid IP address":
                        to_be_updated.exporterErrorLog = connectorStatusReason
                    flag = False

                # Returned from the script after checking the status

                if connectorStatusReason == "FAILED TO CONFIGURED" or connectorStatusReason == "NODE-EXPORTER FILE IS NOT DOWNLOADED SUCCESSFULLY" or connectorStatusReason == "SCRIPT IS NOT EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY":
                    flag = False

                if flag == True:
                    to_be_updated.connectorStatus = "SUCCESS"
                    to_be_updated.save()
                    username = ""
                    password = ""
                    if (data[2]) == '4.188.241.55':
                        username = "APM"
                        password = "APM@12345678"
                    elif (data[2]) == '20.219.4.236':
                        username = "APM2"
                        password = "APM2@12345678"
                    job_name = prometheusConfigurationFileUpdation(
                        data[2], data[3], username, password)
                    print("-----Job name----", job_name)
                    try:
                        thread = threading.Thread(
                            target=checkprometheusTargetStatus, args=(job_name,))

                        thread.start()
                    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                        print("Exception: json decode error")
                        print(str(e))

                    except Exception as e:
                        # return HttpResponse(str(e))
                        print("Inside catch all")
                        print(str(e))

                    if to_be_updated_request.jobStatus != "FAILED":
                        to_be_updated_request.jobStatus = "SUCCESS"
                        to_be_updated_request.save()

                if flag == False:
                    to_be_updated.connectorStatus = "FAILED"
                    to_be_updated.save()
                    to_be_updated_request.jobStatus = "FAILED"
                    to_be_updated_request.save()

                conf_data_dict['Request ID'] = request_id
                conf_data_dict['Connector Status'] = to_be_updated.connectorStatus
                conf_data_dict['VM IP'] = data[2]
                conf_data_dict['Job Start Time'] = to_be_updated.jobStartTime
                conf_data_dict['Connector Status Reason'] = to_be_updated.connectorStatusReason
                conf_data_dict['Tracking ID'] = to_be_updated.trackingID

                conf_data_list.append(conf_data_dict)

            return JsonResponse(conf_data_list, safe=False)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse("Captured exception in MultipleMonitoringConfiguration :-" + repr(e))
    return HttpResponse("Invalid Request method selected")
```

## Functions in prometheus.py

```
def prometheusConfigurationFileUpdation(vm, connector, username, password):
    try:
        # Connect to the VM
        ssh_client1 = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client1.connect(hostname='20.235.82.16',
                            username='Pro', password='Pro@12345678')
        ssh_client2 = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client2.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client2.connect(hostname=vm,
                            username=username, password=password)
        prometheus_config_path = '/Prometheus/prometheus-2.44.0.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml'

        # Read the contents of prometheus.yml
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client1.exec_command(
            f"cat {prometheus_config_path}")
        config_content = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

        # Parse the YAML content into a data structure
        config = yaml.safe_load(config_content)

        # Modify the scrape_configs data structure
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client2.exec_command(
            "sudo ss -tlnp | awk '/node_exporter/ {split($4, a, \":\"); print a[length(a)]}'")
        port_numbers = stdout.read().decode()
        print("Port no: ", port_numbers)
        print("Type of port no.-> ", type(port_numbers))
        if port_numbers:
            port_number = port_numbers.split("\n")[0]
            job_name = f"{connector}-{vm}".strip()
            new_scrape_config = {
                'job_name': job_name,
                'scrape_interval': '5s',
                'static_configs': [
                    {'targets': [f'{vm}:{port_number}'.strip()]}
                ]
            }
            new_job = True
            for scrape_config in config['scrape_configs']:
                if scrape_config['job_name'] == job_name:
                    new_job = False
                    break
            to_be_updated = StatusTracking.objects.get(
                vm=vm, connector=connector, connectorStatus='SUCCESS')
            if new_job == True:
                config['scrape_configs'].append(new_scrape_config)

                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>After appending", config)
                # Serialize the modified data structure back to YAML
                modified_yaml = yaml.dump(config, default_flow_style=False)

                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.modified_yaml:", modified_yaml)
                # Write the modified YAML back to prometheus.yml on the VM
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client1.exec_command(
                    f"echo '{modified_yaml}' | sudo tee {prometheus_config_path} > /dev/null")

                config_content = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.updated one:-", config_content)

                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client1.exec_command(
                    f"pgrep prometheus")
                pid = stdout.read().decode()
                print("old:", pid)
                ssh_client1.exec_command(f"sudo kill -15 {pid}")

                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client1.exec_command(
                    "sudo nohup systemctl restart prometheus &")
                print(stdout.read().decode())
                print(stderr.read().decode())

                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client1.exec_command(
                    f"pgrep prometheus")
                pid = stdout.read().decode()

                print("new", pid)
                return job_name
            else:
                to_be_updated.prometheusErrorLog = "TARGET ALREADY EXISTS"
                to_be_updated.save()
                return ""
    except Exception as e:
        to_be_updated.prometheusErrorLog = f"ERROR-MSG: {str(e)}"
        to_be_updated.save()
        return "ERROR-MSG: ", str(e)

    finally:
        # Close the SSH connection
        ssh_client1.close()
        ssh_client2.close()


def checkprometheusTargetStatus(job_name: str):
    time.sleep(15)
    if re.match(r"\w+-\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", job_name):
        print("---**** Job name ****--- ", job_name)
        [connector, vm] = job_name.split('-', 1)
        url = f'http://20.235.82.16:9090/api/v1/targets?scrapePool={job_name}'
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            print("response status code: ", response.status_code)
            try:
                response_json = response.json()
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                raise json.JSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
            print("response_json :", response_json)
            to_be_updated = StatusTracking.objects.get(
                vm=vm, connector=connector, connectorStatus='SUCCESS')
            if response.status_code == 200 and response_json['status'] == 'success':
                if response_json['data']['activeTargets']:
                    target = response_json['data']['activeTargets'][0]
                    if target['health'] == 'up':
                        to_be_updated.prometheusTargetStatus = "UP"
                        print(f"The target  is up.")
                    else:
                        to_be_updated.prometheusTargetStatus = "DOWN"
                        print(f"The target is down.")
                    if target['lastError']:
                        to_be_updated.prometheusErrorLog = target['lastError']
                else:
                    to_be_updated.prometheusErrorLog = "TARGET DOES NOT EXIST OR HAS NO DATA"
                    print(
                        f"The target does not exist or has no data.")
            else:
                to_be_updated.prometheusErrorLog = "FAILURE IN RETREIVING TARGET STATUS"
                print(
                    f"Failed to retrieve the status for the target '{target}'.")
            to_be_updated.save()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            raise Exception(str(e))
```